# How do I get a array variable to save as the file name output?

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I am trying to write a C# program with very little programming experience to intake a csv file and output a XML file.  This works, but I am trying to now modify the program to where it will output a XML file for each line of the CSV, and name the XML file equal to the fields[0] "name" value.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the compiler is saying the name "fields" does not exist in the current context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace CSVtoXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Read into an array of strings.
            string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("import.csv");
            foreach (string line in source)
            {
                XElement cust = new XElement("Root",
                    from str in source
                    let fields = str.Split(',')
                    select new XElement("other_asset",
                        new XElement("name", fields[0]),
                        new XElement("status", new XElement("name", fields[1])),
                        new XElement("asset_type", new XElement("name", fields[2])),
                        new XElement("ip", fields[3]),
                        new XElement("manufacturer", fields[4]),
                        new XElement("model", fields[5]),
                        new XElement("serial_number", fields[6]),
                        new XElement("site", new XElement("name", fields[7])),
                        new XElement("department", new XElement("name", fields[8])),
                        new XElement("custom_field",
                            new XElement("location", fields[9]),
                            new XElement("Mac_Address", fields[10]),
                            new XElement("End_User", fields[11]),
                            new XElement("Notes", fields[12])
                        )
                    )
                );
                cust.Save(fields[0] + ".xml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fields` does not exist in the scope where you call `Save`. The easiest fix is to introduce a `string fileName;` before `XElement...`, assign the `fields[0]` value to it after the `str.Split` call, then use the `fileName` variable in place of `fields[0]` in the `Save` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is right. `fields` is local variable which is visible only within the LINQ query. But I don't think you need the LINQ query at all. Just assign `line.Split(',')` to local variable and use it to create `XDocument` and file name.

Something like

```
foreach (string line in source)
{
    var fields = line.Split(',');

    XElement cust =
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("other_asset",
                new XElement("name", fields[0]),
                new XElement("status", new XElement("name", fields[1])),
                new XElement("asset_type", new XElement("name", fields[2])),
                new XElement("ip", fields[3]),
                new XElement("manufacturer", fields[4]),
                new XElement("model", fields[5]),
                new XElement("serial_number", fields[6]),
                new XElement("site", new XElement("name", fields[7])),
                new XElement("department", new XElement("name", fields[8])),
                new XElement("custom_field",
                    new XElement("location", fields[9]),
                    new XElement("Mac_Address", fields[10]),
                    new XElement("End_User", fields[11]),
                    new XElement("Notes", fields[12])
                )
            )
        );

    cust.Save(fields[0] + ".xml");
}
```